# Как выдать роль при нажатии на реакцию в discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Я хочу реализовать кое-какую игру. Чтобы войти в игровую комнату пользователь должен нажать на реакцию.

Код:

```
import discord as ds
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=ds.Intents.all())
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join( member ):
  role = ds.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Вне игры')
  role2 = ds.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name='Игрок')
  await member.add_roles(role, role2)

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
  msg = await ctx.send('Чтобы войти или создать комнату нажмите на реакцию')
  await msg.add_reaction('✅')

bot.run('token')
```

Как проверить, нажал ли пользователь на реакцию?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        message_id = payload.message_id
        if message_id == message_id:
            guild_id = payload.guild_id
            guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, self.bot.guilds)

            if payload.emoji.id == emoji_id:
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=emoji_id)                
            else:
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = payload.emoji.name)

            if role:
                member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
                if member:
                    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: ```File "main.py", line 18
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent```

Comment: Учите базовый синтаксис языка